# Swapping positions between 2 sprites with different parents

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

im trying to swap positions between spriteA and SpriteB. They have parents: parentA and parentB. Im also changing parents.
So if i just swap without animation it works OK.
But if i run CCMoveTo action, sprites get dispositioned at the start of the action and then moving towards the specified positions. What i need is so they dont blink and move from their position to specified positions. Parent are being rotated, and childs are not rotated because i use child.rotation=-child.parent.protation.
here is my code

```
-(void)makeSwapBetweenSelectedShape:(ShapeSprite*)firstShape secondShape:(ShapeSprite*)secondShape{
CGPoint positionOfFirst=[firstShape.parent convertToNodeSpace:firstShape.position];
CGPoint positionOfSecond=secondShape.position;

NSLog(@"POSITION BEFORE 1st %f %f",[firstShape.parent convertToWorldSpace:firstShape.position].x,[firstShape.parent convertToWorldSpace:firstShape.position].y);
NSLog(@"POSITION BEFORE 2nd %f %f",[secondShape.parent convertToWorldSpace:secondShape.position].x,[secondShape.parent convertToWorldSpace:secondShape.position].y);   

//swapping parents
CCNode* tempParent=firstShape.parent;
[firstShape removeFromParentAndCleanup:NO];
[secondShape.parent addChild:firstShape];
[firstShape runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.1 position:positionOfSecond],[CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode* node){
 NSLog(@"POSITION AFTER ANIMATION 1st %f %f ",[node.parent convertToWorldSpace:node.position].x,[node.parent convertToWorldSpace:node.position].y);
}],nil]];
NSLog(@"POSITION ON START 1st %f %f ",[firstShape.parent convertToWorldSpace:firstShape.position].x,[firstShape.parent convertToWorldSpace:firstShape.position].y);


[secondShape removeFromParentAndCleanup:NO];
[tempParent addChild:secondShape];

[secondShape runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.1 position:selectedShapeStartingPosition],[CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode* node){
    NSLog(@"POSITION AFTER ANIMATION 2st %f %f ",[node.parent convertToWorldSpace:node.position].x,[node.parent convertToWorldSpace:node.position].y);

}],nil]];

NSLog(@"POSITION ON START 2nd %f %f",[secondShape.parent convertToWorldSpace:secondShape.position].x,[secondShape.parent convertToWorldSpace:secondShape.position].y);


}
```

gives me this log:

```
2013-10-30 19:36:54.397 Wheel[1254:a0b] POSITION BEFORE 1st 160.000000 248.000000
2013-10-30 19:36:54.397 Wheel[1254:a0b] POSITION BEFORE 2nd 160.000000 204.000000
2013-10-30 19:36:54.398 Wheel[1254:a0b] POSITION ON START 1st 116.000000 204.000000 
2013-10-30 19:36:54.398 Wheel[1254:a0b] POSITION ON START 2nd 204.000000 248.000000
2013-10-30 19:36:55.533 Wheel[1254:a0b] POSITION AFTER ANIMATION 1st 160.000000 204.000000 
2013-10-30 19:36:55.534 Wheel[1254:a0b] POSITION AFTER ANIMATION 2st 160.000000 248.000000
```

Edit: Added NSLog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it.
The right code is:

```
-(void)makeSwapBetweenSelectedShape:(ShapeSprite*)firstShape secondShape:(ShapeSprite*)secondShape{

    CGPoint positionOfFirst=firstShape.position;
    CGPoint positionOfSecond=secondShape.position;

    CGPoint worldPositionOfFirst=[firstShape.parent convertToWorldSpace:firstShape.position];
    CGPoint worldPositionOfSecond=[secondShape.parent convertToWorldSpace:secondShape.position];

    //swapping parents
    CCNode* tempParent=firstShape.parent;
    [firstShape removeFromParentAndCleanup:NO];
    [secondShape.parent addChild:firstShape];
    firstShape.position=[firstShape.parent convertToNodeSpace:worldPositionOfFirst];
    [firstShape runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.5 position:positionOfSecond]];


    [secondShape removeFromParentAndCleanup:NO];
    [tempParent addChild:secondShape];
    secondShape.position=[secondShape.parent convertToNodeSpace:worldPositionOfSecond];
    [secondShape runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.5 position:positionOfFirst]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In cocos child position is specified in parent coordinates, so unless your `parentA` and `parentB` have the same size and position, you need to translate their children coordinates to new parent. So your code should look like this :

```
-(void)makeSwapBetweenSelectedShape:(ShapeSprite*)firstShape secondShape(ShapeSprite*)secondShape{
    CGPoint positionOfFirst=firstShape.position;
    CGPoint positionOfSecond=secondShape.position;

    // this is to make firstShape position be represented in secondShape parents coordinates
    CGPoint positionOfFirstTranslated = [secondShape.parent convertToNodeSpace:positionOfFirst];

    //analogically
    CGPoint positionOfSecondTranslated = [firstShape.parent convertToNodeSpace:positionOfSecond];

    //swapping parents
    CCNode* tempParent=firstShape.parent;
    [firstShape removeFromParentAndCleanup:NO];
    [firstShape setPosition:positionOfFirstTranslated];
    [secondShape.parent addChild:firstShape];
    [firstShape runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.1 position:positionOfSecond]];
    [secondShape removeFromParentAndCleanup:NO];
    [secondShape setPosition:positionOfSecondTranslated];
    [tempParent addChild:secondShape];
    [secondShape runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.1 position:positionOfFirst]];
}
```

Edit : changed the code to match the expectations of OP, based on the comment.

Comment: the problem is not that they are moving to the wrong destination, the problem is that when they start moving they blink from their positions to some random positions and then start moving towards specified location, its like initial position is wrong. I want them to move from their current position to specified, instead of blinking from current to some random then move to specified.

Comment: despite of this code looking logically right, unfortunately it doesnt fix the problem either, sprites start moving from even further distance, nearly from the left bottom corner of the screen.

Comment: may be it will help: parents can be rotated, when i rotate em, sprites start moving from even more further distance.